# How to know when to use Shihor or Nile?

Tags: word-study, isaiah, jeremiah, joshua, word-choice

In Joshua 13:3 (NASB)

> from the **Shihor** which is east of Egypt, even as far as the border of Ekron to the north (it is counted as Canaanite); the five governors of the Philistines: the Gazite, the Ashdodite, the Ashkelonite, the Gittite, the Ekronite; and the Avvite

The word used for Shihor is Strong's H7883 - šîḥôr. That exact same word in other locations is translated as Nile, instead. For instances,

- in Isaiah 23:3 (NASB)

> And were on many waters.
>
> The grain of the **Nile**, the harvest of the River was her revenue;
>
> And she was the market of nations.

- in Jeremiah 2:18 (NASB)

> But now what are you doing on the road to Egypt,
>
> Except to drink the waters of the **Nile**?
>
> Or what are you doing on the road to Assyria,
>
> Except to drink the waters of the Euphrates River?

How to know when to use Shihor or Nile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we are discussing two different words here:

- שִׁיחוֹר (Shichor) occurs only four times in the OT and according to BDB is:

> proper name, of a river on border of Egypt, probably east branch of
> Nile; — ׳הַשּׁ Joshua 13:3, מִצְרַיִם ׳שׁ 1 Chronicles 13:5; clearly =
> Nile, זֶרַע שִׁחֹר Isaiah 23:3 ("" יְאוֺר קְצִיר), מֵי שִׁחוֺר
> Jeremiah 2:18; compare DlPa 311 WilsonHast. DB SHIHOR (usually derived
> from I. שׁחר, as black water, but doubtful).

- יְאֹר (yeor) occurs 65 times in the OT and according to BDB is:

> יְאֹר, יְאוֺר noun masculineExodus 7:21 stream of the Nile, stream,
> canal (Egyptian loan-word = Egyptian °iotr, °io°r, watercourse, Coptic
> eioor, ior; also °iotr±o, °io°r±o, Coptic eiero, iaro, Nile, SteindBAs
> i. 612; in Assyrian ia°uru, stream, °Iaru°û, river Nile, Idib., Hptib.
> 171 Jägerib 466) — absolute הַיְאֹר Genesis 41:1 37t.; הַיְאוֺר Isaiah
> 19:8; הַיְאֹ֫רָה Exodus 1:22; יְאוֺר Isaiah 19:7 (3 t. in verse) +
> 2t.; כָּאֹר (err. for כַּיְאֹר) Amos 8:8; construct כִּיאֹר Amos 9:5;
> כִּיאוֺר Amos 8:8; suffix יְאֹרִי Ezekiel 29:3b (Co יאר, compare
> Ezekiel 29:9 and ᵑ6 ᵑ7); plural יְאֹרִים Exodus 8:1 4t.; construct
> יְאֹרֵי Isaiah 7:18 2t.; יְאוֺרֵי 2 Kings 19:24; suffix יְאֹרֶיךָ
> Ezekiel 29:4 (twice in verse); Ezekiel 29:5 + Ezekiel 29:4 (strike out
> ᵐ5 Co) + Ezekiel 29:10 (Co יְאֹרְךָ); יְאֹרָיו Ezekiel 29:3;
> יְאֹדֵיהֶם Exodus 7:19; Psalm 78:44; — 1 stream of the Nile, river
> Nile, usually with article Genesis 41:1,2,3 (twice in verse); Genesis
> 41:18; Exodus 1:22; Exodus 2:3,5 (twice in verse); Exodus 4:9 (twice
> in verse); Exodus 7:15,17,18 (3 t. in verse); Exodus 7:20 (twice in
> verse); Exodus 7:21 (3 t. in verse); Exodus 7:24 (twice in verse);
> Exodus 7:28; Exodus 8:5; Exodus 8:7; Exodus 17:5 (all J E), Amos 8:8;
> Amos 9:5; Isaiah 19:7 (3 t. in verse); Isaiah 19:8; Isaiah 23:3 (""
> שִׁחֹר), Isaiah 23:10; Jeremiah 46:7,8 (simile of Egyptian invasion),
> Ezekiel 29:3b (read יאר, see above), Ezekiel 29:9; Zechariah 10:11;
> more fully יְאֹר מִצְרַיִם Amos 8:8; Amos 9:5.
>
> 2 plural:
>
> a. Nile-arms, Nile-canals, יְאֹרֵי מִצְרַים Isaiah 7:18; יְאֹרֵי
> מָצוֺר Isaiah 19:6 ("" נְהָרוֺת), Isaiah 37:25 = 2 Kings 19:24; see
> also Nahum 3:8; Exodus 7:19; Exodus 8:1 (both P; "" נְהָרֹת,
> אֲגַמִּים, etc.), Psalm 78:44 ("" נֹזְלִים), Ezekiel 29:3,4 (twice in
> verse); Ezekiel 29:5,10 + Ezekiel 29:4 ᵑ0 (but strike out ᵐ5 Co),
> Ezekiel 30:12.
>
> b. watercourses in General, יְאֹרִים רַחֲבֵי יָדָ֑יִם Isaiah 33:21 (""
> נְהָרִים; compare Late Hebrew יְאוֺר, late Aramaic יְאוֺרָא).
>
> 3 shafts, made in mining Job 28:10 (בַּצּוּרוֺת).
>
> 4 יְאֹר, singular, of Tigris, Daniel 12:5 (twice in verse); Daniel
> 12:6,7 (compare Daniel 10:4).
>
> כָּאֹר Amos 8:8, see יְאֹר.